# Create records in separate table when user registers new account

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

Im creating a `WebBrowser` game with `Symfony2`. What I want to achieve is:
I have a table with Users. When new user registers in the game, new record is added to table `fos_user`. When new user is registered I also want to put records in the table that stores users resources in the game with starting quantity.

I have read about event listeners but I'm not sure if they are the best way to resolve my problem.

This is the Entity that holds User, type of material and its quantity

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="quantity", type="bigint")
 */
private $quantity;





/*
 * connection material->MaterialStock<-User
 */

/**
 *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Material", inversedBy="userMaterial") 
 * 
 */
private $material;


/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="userMaterial") 
 */
private $user;


function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}
function getQuantity() {
    return $this->quantity;
}
function getMaterial() {
    return $this->material;
}
function getUser() {
    return $this->user;
}
function setQuantity($quantity) {
    $this->quantity = $quantity;
}
function setMaterial($material) {
    $this->material = $material;
}
function setUser($user) {
    $this->user = $user;
}
}
```

User entity looks like this

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php
namespace FactoryBundle\Entity;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FactoryBundle\Entity\Factory;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
*/
class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * 
 */
protected $id;


public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->productionOrders = new ArrayCollection();


}

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Factory", mappedBy="user")
 */

private $factory;





/*
 * connecting User->materialStock<-Material
 */
/**
 *
 *  @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MaterialStock", mappedBy="user") 
 */
private $userMaterial;



/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductionOrders", mappedBy="user")
 */
private $productionOrders;

/** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ToyStock", mappedBy="user") */
private $userToyStock;


function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}
function getFactory() {
    return $this->factory;
}
function getUserMaterial() {
    return $this->userMaterial;
}
function getProductionOrders() {
    return $this->productionOrders;
}
function getUserToyStock() {
    return $this->userToyStock;
}
function setId($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
}
function setFactory($factory) {
    $this->factory = $factory;
}
function setUserMaterial($userMaterial) {
    $this->userMaterial = $userMaterial;
}
function setProductionOrders($productionOrders) {
    $this->productionOrders = $productionOrders;
}
function setUserToyStock($userToyStock) {
    $this->userToyStock = $userToyStock;
} 
}
```

Comment: Yep.  Symfony (not Doctrine) event  listener is what you need.  You will need to be using the alpha or dev version of fos user bundle which generates an event when a new user is registered.  Listen for the event and then do whatever additional processing is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an event subscriber.

```
<?php

namespace ...;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
use Steora\Api\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use ...\EntityThatHoldsUserTypeOfMaterialAndQuantity;

/**
 * ...
 */
class RegistrationCompletionListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /** @var EntityManager */
    private $em;

    /**
     * @param EntityManager $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED => 'onRegistrationCompletionSuccess',
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param FilterUserResponseEvent $event
     */
    public function onRegistrationCompletionSuccess(FilterUserResponseEvent $event)
    {
        // you can modify response here, but you can remove this line if there is no need to touch response...
        $response = $event->getResponse();

        $user = $event->getUser();

        $entityThatHoldsUserTypeOfMaterialAndQuantity = new EntityThatHoldsUserTypeOfMaterialAndQuantity();

        $entityThatHoldsUserTypeOfMaterialAndQuantity->setUser($user);
        $entityThatHoldsUserTypeOfMaterialAndQuantity->setQuantity(...);
        ...

        $this->em->persist($entityThatHoldsUserTypeOfMaterialAndQuantity);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

Register your service in service.yml

```
services:
    ...
    steora.api.user.registration_confirmation:
        class: YourBundle\..\RegistrationCompletionListener
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager']
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

So, you are listening for some event, and when that event happens, you do stuff that you need :)

Here you can find more events, maybe some other than FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED is more suitable for you: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/FOSUserEvents.php

Here is an example from the official docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/controller_events.html

---

This is workflow:

1) A user is filling a registration form and submits his data.

2) If the form is valid, this is what happens:

```
// friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Controller/RegistrationController.php

if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

        $userManager->updateUser($user);

        if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        }

        // This is event you are listening for!!!!
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

        return $response;
    }

    $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_FAILURE, $event);

    if (null !== $response = $event->getResponse()) {
        return $response;
    }
}
```

3) Your listener reacts on event, and in onRegistrationCompletionSuccess() you do your stuff, and after that everything continues as usual :)

Answer (score 0):

Matko Đipalo
Thank you for your answer. If I understood you correctly the workflow of your approach is:

`FOSUser:RegistrationController.php` creates an event when registration is completed

```
$dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));
```

in your class `RegistrationCompletionListener` in line:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED => 'onRegistrationCompletionSuccess',
    );
}enter code here
```

Im specifieing to what events I want my app to listen too and on line:

```
public function onRegistrationCompletionSuccess(FilterUserResponseEvent $event)
{
    $response = $event->getResponse();
    //... make needed actions
    $this->yourDependencies->doSomeStufff()...
}
```

I can tell me script what to do when that event will accour. In my case get the user object and create for him records in database.